# Filter Crystal Report by combobox values

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

i have 2 comboboxes cmb1 and cmb2, a button and a crystalreportviewer , cmb1 displays Std and cmb2 displays Div,both values are extracted from database.I am new to crystal report and confusd how to use selection field and all ..i want that when i select either or both comboboxes and click the button the data should be filtered in crystal report and displayed in the crystalreportviewer..eg. i select '5' in cmb1 and 'A' in cmb2 then records from class 5 A only should be displayed .. 
C# VS2008 , default crystal report with VS2008 ..
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There can be two ways to do this thing

1) Firstly you have to filter the data table with respect combo's value at front end and then reassign the filtered data table to crystal report by using SetDataSource() function.

```
 rptMembership objMembership = new rptMembership();
 DataView dv =new DataView(ReportDataTable);    
 // Filtering data on combo values.
 dv.Filter = "combo1id = 1 and combo2id = 2"
 objMembership.SetDataSource(dv.ToTable());
 rptViewer.ReportSource =  objMembership;
```

2) Secondly you can do by filtering the record at database end as per your combo value and then re assign new data table to crystal.

There is no direct way of filtering the records at crystal report level.

Comment: Please try this code and let me know either your problem is resolved. if not then share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in the combo-box:

```
        report rd = new report();

        // set database login information
        rd.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password", @"NOHA-PC\SQLEXPRESS", "dbname");

        // write formula to pass parameters to report
        crystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{tablename.columnname} =" + comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
```